# Business Entity called Task - what to call my software class

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am building a project management system in .NET C# that deals with (physical construction) tasks to be completed by workers.

My knowledge of DDD tells me I should use a ubiquitous language - and use the same terms that are used by the business.

However I feel calling a class Task in my classes will be a horrible experience for programmers  getting confused between Software Threading Tasks and the real world tasks.

Any advice on how best to handle situations like these?

Comment: Might be a good question for [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I agree with @Cyral, but I will say that there are plenty of cases where classes are named the same.  That's what namespaces are for.

Comment: namespaces are your friend. But it happens alot. System.Data.DataTable and Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interop.DataTable, perfect example.

Comment: That's why you have bounded contexts, usually implemented as namespaces/packages. The ubiquitous language only make sense within a bounded context. The same term can have different meanings depending on that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason not to call it Task. If this is the language that you have agreed upon with the domain experts (and it makes sense for both of you), then this is the language you should be using. As mentioned in the comments, in your bounded context task would mean what you define them to mean.

If you write you code well, the ambiguity will be a minimum. You will find that you rarely deal with the two different task concepts in the same context, and by following single responsibility principle you will limit the confusion even more.

And if you do have ambiguity, use your namespaces and make it clear that you are working with a model, and not a programming concept.